# What pasta sauces can I make that don't include cheese?

Tags: sauce, pasta, dairy-free

I've been making a fairly standard arrabbiata sauce for months, and I'd like to expand the number of sauces I can make.

However, many of these recipes involve cheese and/or milk, but I'm sadly lactose intolerant and would prefer to avoid these ingredients.

What others sauces could I be making, and what pasta should I use with them?

Comment: This is very broad. Apart from the many different tomato sauces there are loads of others, such as alglio e olio (garlic and oil). I'm told some vegan cheeses are good enough to melt into a sauce now as well

Comment: Consider some Asian-type sauces too. Won't go that amazing with egg noodles, but if you like noodles in general, a good Thai Peanut sauce, mandarin ginger, or others are great!

Comment: It's not a direct answer to what you asked, so I am commenting -- but I have successfully used soy milk in some pasta sauce recipes that call for milk. (Soy cheese, however, are more hit-or-miss.) Searching for "vegan `saucename`" can help.

Comment: Another option is to take a carbonara recipe and omit the cheese (carbonara shouldn't have cream anyway, the creaminess comes from barely-cooked egg) making sure you have plenty of other flavour in there

Comment: Sorry, that's a perfect example of a "big-list" question. They are not acceppted on virtually all Stack Exchange sites. Generally, if you wonder what you should choose to cook (which dish, or which recipe for a given dish), this ends up being a question we cannot answer.

Answer (score 13):

- Tomato Sauce
- Putanesca
- Pesto (omit parmesan)
- Bolognese (meat sauce)
- Squash Puree (maybe with sage)
- Olive oil infusions (fresh herb/garlic/chilis/lemon zest)
- Roasted Red Pepper puree sauce
- etc

Comment: Adding a bit of miso to no-cheese pesto can add back in a bit of the Parmesan flavor.

Comment: Note that Many Bolognese recipes include milk (but you can leave it out).

Comment: Nutritional yeast flakes are another option for replacing the cheese in pesto.  In either case, use a specific recipe for a cheese-free pesto — don’t just use a traditional recipe minus the cheese.  A good cheese-free pesto will have the proportions of the other ingredients rebalanced: typically a little more oil and nuts (to make up for the missing fat from the cheese), and often a little vinegar or citrus for acidity.

Answer (score 8):

There are very few pasta sauces recipe that actually uses cheese or milk products in their recipes.
The ones that use cheese are easy to spot (caccio e pepe, carbonara...) so don't do them.

You could use lactose free cheese or milk or cream.

Remember that real Parmesan contain very little to no lactose.

To add to other suggestions, have a look at any sauces that use seafood and shellfish, they mostly are based on oil and tomatoes anyway.

Comment: Depending on the degree of lactose intolerance, lactose-free dairy may still cause a reaction. (It also sometimes presents with milk protein intolerance or allergy.) Otherwise, though, good suggestions!

Comment: "There are very few pasta sauces recipe that actually uses cheese or milk products in their recipes." Actually, there are very many, and you haven't given one example of one which doesn't, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: Steven above list a few.

Answer (score 2):

As an italian,

- Amatriciana
- Alla norma
- Sauce "alla Fiorentina" (sage, garlic, capers, basil, chives)
- Mushrooms and ham
- Black Cuttlefish (nero di seppia)
- Aretina sauce (sugo all'aretina)
- Mushrooms, nuts and truffle sauce

And many more!